# Shell script to add extension on file

Tags: bash

Need help on this please
Would like a scrip that will receive parameters as directories, browse thoses directories to add the right extension on each file found, or if it is a directory to add .aaa as extension
The files doesnt have any extension, and I have to use the comand file to determine the file type (files do not have extyension) 
Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in "$@"; do
    for file in "$dir"/*;
    do    
        if [[ -d $file ]]
        then
            ext=dir
        else
            file -i * | egrep 'avi|txt|jpeg|pst'
        fi
        if [file eq avi]
            ext=avi
        else
            if [file eq txt]
                ext=txt
            else
                if [file eq jpeg]
                    ext=jpeg
                fi
    done
done
```

Comment: There are some `then`s missing. `[` should be followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean something like this:

```
for dir in "$@"
do
    for file in "$dir"/*
    do
        ftype=$(file -i "$file")
        unset ext
        case $ftype in
            *directory*) ext=aaa
                         ;;
            *avi*) ext=avi
                   ;;
            *text*) ext=txt
                   ;;
            *jpeg*) ext=jpeg 
                    ;;
            *ps*) ext=ps
                  ;;
            *) echo "File '$ftype' not recognised for file $file" >&2
               continue
               ;;
        esac                                                           
        echo "Renaming '$file' to '$file.$ext'"
        mv "$file" "$file.$ext"
    done
done
```

Note that there is no need for `egrep`, and `file` also reports on directories as well, so no need for the `-d` test.

Edit:  `egrep` was in the original posted question.
       Added `unset`